# Good books and resources on data parallel programming and algorithms

Tags: algorithm, design-patterns, gpgpu, gpu

I've read the following and most of the NVIDIA manuals and other content. I was also at [GTC](http://www.nvidia.com/object/gpu_technology_conference.html) last year for the papers and talks.

[CUDA by Example: An Introduction to General-Purpose GPU Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131387685)

[Programming Massively Parallel Processors: A Hands-on Approach](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123814723)

And I'm aware of the latest [GPU Computing Gems Emerald Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123849888) but haven't read it yet.

What other books and resources would you recommend? For instance I'm sure there's some great content from the first wave of data parallel programming in the 80s (the [Connection Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_Machine) etc). I know a lot of research was done on data parallel algorithms for that generation of hardware.

**Followup... 30/Mar/2011**

I also discovered that the GPU Gems books 1-3 have some chapters on GPU computing, not just graphics. They're available free online, http://developer.nvidia.com/object/gpu_gems_home.html. I've not had a chance to read them yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hillis & Steele [1986], ["Data Parallel Algorithms"](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.85.1876&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Comment: This is __exactly__ the sort of thing I was looking for. If people have more please post them.

Answer (score 0):

Optimizing Applications for Mulit-Core Processors - Stewart Taylor (Intel Press)