# actual gpu technique digest similar to GPU Gems series

Tags: gpu

I liked GPU Gems for its structured technology digest. But a long time passed since its last release and new algorithms should be developed for working with new type of hardware.

What can I read about recent GPU technology achievements?

Is lurking on programming boards the only way?

Answer (score 1):

NVidia has a list of [Suggested reading](https://developer.nvidia.com/suggested-reading) which contains the latest GEMS books and some others. By the looks of it there isn't anything better/newer than the Emerald GEMS book.

Your best bet in the light of no new GEMS books is probably to look at some of the presentations and papers from the [GTC Conference](http://www.gputechconf.com/gtcnew/on-demand-gtc.php). These are available on-demand.

BTW: I asked a [question in a similar vein a while back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5304245/good-books-and-resources-on-data-parallel-programming-and-algorithms). [Hillis & Steele [1986], "Data Parallel Algorithms"](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.85.1876&rep=rep1&type=pdf), is very old but still a good read.

Comment: I was very amused after revealing that all modern GPUs are no more vector processing units but consists of universal RISC units interconnected by non-blocking buses. All old books that suppose GPU can do only vector computations are not valid, since much more flexible techniques are available for modern GPUs

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment.

Comment: All old books refers to GPU as vector processor (SIMD). But now all GPU's are actually much more. So many algorithms become irrelevant.